# Is it Possible to write alert message outside javascript functions?

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("message function");
function message()
{
alert("This alert box was called with the onload event");
}
</script>
```

Is it possible to write `alert("message function");` Just after main script tag

Comment: Your question is very unclear... You mean have javascript after </script> ? Try writing the whole HTML here.

Comment: No actually i want to write like this <script> alert("alert"); </script>. If i write like this when this alert message will popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any script or script related functions inside  tag will be interpreted by browser ! else it would be plain text content,unless until sorrounded by html tags

Answer (score 0):

You can write them into html. I dont think you need the semi colon. Also, note that tags are taken out of posts.